# Conditional Highlighting in Word's Mail Merge

Tags: ms-word, highlighting, mailmerge

I have a word document I'm using as a mail merge connected to an Excel spreadsheet. In the word document are a set of tables, each cell populated by one or more fields from the Excel spreadsheet. There are three fields that are meant to turn red when the merge field = 'Red', green when it is 'Green', et cetera. The problem is, conditional formatting won't work in Word, so I have to figure out some way to format these cells without it.

I was hoping for some sort of solution that would utilize the word-merge's If-Then-Else rule, but I don't think that's possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some clarification required - do you for example, have { MERGEFIELD field1 }, { MERGEFIELD field2 } and { MERGEFIELD field3 }, and they all need to be red if { MERGEFIELD colour } is "Red"? Or is each field's colour linked to a different column in the data source? _And_ are you trying to colour the entire cell, or just the result text? _And_ do you have a small (how large?), finite number of possible colours? Trouble is, some of these possibilities arguably need code to solve them (good fit for StackOverflow) and some don't (not really in the scope of StackOverflow, best post elsewhere!)